# Wordpress Multisite Subdirectory dashboard redirecting to the subdirectory homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, admin

I have been stuck in a problem with a WordPress Multisite subdirectory.
I have a network of multisites. My sites are like this:

1. mysite.com (main)
2. mysite.com/second
3. mysite.com/third

Basically, the main site and the second site is working fine. It does not show any errors and there are no problems with they're wp-admin as well.

But the third sites all have issues admin panel. When I open the third site admin panel, it give redirected to third site homepage.
So the homepage working well but only have problem with the admin panel and can't get access to third site admin panel.

I am pretty sure that it is a .htaccess error but I can’t seem to find the solution for it.

The network multisites wp-config.php and .htaccess looking like lines below.

Wp-config :

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Try commenting out the last line `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` . Change it to `#RewriteRule . index.php [L]` just to see  if it works

Comment: _“I am pretty sure that it is a .htaccess error”_ - I don’t see how that would explain why it was working correctly for the site under the `/second/` path, but not for that under the `/third/` path. I’d start by checking the settings for those sites, and verify that `Siteurl` and `Home` are set correctly in each case.

Comment: @Amit Verma, I just commented out the line, but getting "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @CBroe, actually I created the /fourth/ path and it's also working well, the only problem is with /third/ path.

Comment: So did you check the site settings, or not?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed and the problem was with admin role. I don't know why the admin role was changed to customer and I just changed the admin role to Administrator and the problem was gone.